# How to handle spinners using protractor if spinner hidden by wrapper

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

During writing test for Angular app using Protractor, I faced a lot of problem related to handling spinners, some of then I solved, but I don't know how to test spinners which hidden by wrapper, for example if parent tag have ng-if, or ng-hide statements, and spinner has a height and width that is greater than 0.
I have tried to use:

```
spinner.isDisplayed();
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(spinner), 5000);
```

HTML examples (parent tag could be different):

```
 <div class="some purent div">
 <div class="spinner-loader small-loader ng-hide" ng-show="expression">  </div>
</div>
```

:::

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="spinner-loader spinner-dark" ng-if="if_statement"></div>
</div>
```

:::

```
<div ng-show='exp'>
...
 <div>
...
  <div class='spinner'></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

but it's hasn't worked. Please help...!

Comment: Can you provide the HTML of the spinner when it's visible and hidden?

Comment: added, couple examples, please notice, parent tag for spinner could be different, and sometimes ng-if and ng-hide could be located on couple tags higher

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
element.all(by.model('model of your spinner')).each(function (eachElement, index)
{
     eachElement.click();
     browser.driver.sleep(500);
     element(by.css('Unique identifier of the Spinner value you are selecting')).click();
     browser.driver.sleep(500);
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Waiting for a specific amount of time is a bad practice since the response time for web page is variable. What if it takes slightly more than the defined time to display the element?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fragments of html your provided, you could get the visible spinners with :

```
By.cssLocator(".spinner-loader:not(.ng-hide):not([ng-if]) .spinner")
```

And to get the hidden spinners :

```
By.cssLocator(".spinner-loader.ng-hide .spinner, .spinner-loader[ng-if] .spinner")
```

Comment: What about such case: <div class="wrapper">...<div class="spinner-loader"></div>...</div>, and parent element dynamically could receive style like "display:none", could you please advice something ?

Comment: Trying to get an answer case by case is no ideal. I would first list all the cases, then define the rules and finally build the selectors and ask for help if required.